# Inductors Vs. Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, inductor

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a capacitor in filter circuits instead of other passive elements?

Comment: chalk vs. cheese

Comment: Simple: inductors are bulky. You can't just print out a 3D spiral of thin wire. (OK, there are some chips that use conductive strips "wound up" "around" bilayer PCBs as rudimentary inductors to sense magnetic field, but that's it)

Comment: Inductors block high frequency signals and conduct low frequency signals, while capacitors do the reverse too, right?

Comment: @AceClub depends on the circuit arrangement. Both can be used for highpass/lowpass filters.

Comment: Inductors don't *block* high frequency signals any more than capacitors *block* low frequency signals.  It's not binary 'block or conduct' behaviour.  Rather, the impedance of an inductor is *proportional* to the frequency (increases with increasing frequency) while the impedance of a capacitor is *inversely proportional* to the frequency (decreases with increasing frequency).

Comment: I have figured it out myself guys but thanks for the help. My professor was asking something totally different from what I posted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to block dc but let frequencies above 20 Hz through largely unaffected (as in a simple audio amplifier), the time constant of your circuit will need to be about 0.01.

Additionally, if you want an input impedance of at least 1 kohm (ball-park for audio) you will find that the inductive or capacitive Reactance at 20 Hz needs to be also 1 kohm: -

[image]

Try an inductor for size: -

X is 1000 =\$2\pi 20Hz \cdot L\$

Therefore L is approximately 10 henries.

Try a capacitor for size:

1000 =\$\dfrac{1}{2\pi 20Hz \cdot C}\$

C will be about 10uF.

Go to a suppliers website and see how big the L and C are and their relative costs.

That should give you your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andy aka said, cost is a big issue. There's no reason to use a part that is more expensive or takes up more space than a better alternative.

One other thing to consider is EMC. Remember capacitors store energy in the form of electric fields and inductors store energy in the form of magnetic fields. Therefore, if you have a circuit that emits a great amount of say, magnetic fields, or it is particularly susceptible to them, it is best to avoid inductors and use capacitors. The same is true for the opposite case. That said, sometimes it could even be cheaper in the long run to implement a more complex, active filter using an op-amp than it would be to implement a simple LC filter if you avoid EMC issues.

Another thing to consider is packaging. You may just not have room for a big inductor. On the other hand, it may be easier to use a ferrite as a low pass filter to attenuate high frequency noise than to implement an RC LPF on a PCB. What passive components to use really depends on the device as a whole. Cost, space, and frequency are some of the main concerns.